# How I can change the home directory of the sftp server on MAC OS X?

Tags: terminal, osx, users, sftp, working-directory

I'm trying to set up SFTP's home directory on a MAC OS X Mavericks for user my_user. Now, it looks like:

`/Users/my_user` (i got it with ***sftp> pwd*** command)

but I want it be:

```
/Users/my_user/Documents/new/dirs
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify if you want to change actual home directory of user or starting directory of `sftp`. The first is not a good idea to change, but you can certainly do that using your user settings.

The start directory of your user can be set up in `sshd_config`, where you define `sftp` subsystem, like this (path on Mac will be probably different):

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

By adding `-d start_directory` option to this line you are able to change starting directory as described in manual page:

> `-d start_directory`
>
> specifies an alternate starting directory for users.  The pathname may contain the following tokens that are expanded at runtime: %% is replaced by a literal '%', %d is replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated, and %u is replaced by the username of that user.  The default is to use the user's home directory. [...]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!) sshd_config on a MAC OS X is located here: /private/etc/httpd_config.