# SFTP: New files can be Create-But-Don't-Modify. How to do this with new directories?

Tags: permissions, openssh, sftp

I've figured out how to accomplish a "create-but-don't-modify" permission scheme using SFTP. But it works for files only; I'd like to expand it to directories.

---

**Background:**

I have an SFTP server (OpenSSH-based) which confines a specific user group to a common [chroot jail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/105/275847) directory. The configuration is similar to that in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/293756/275847) conversation.

I want users in this group to be able to create files and directories but not modify or delete them once created. I can't do this directly, as standard Linux permissions do not differentiate between "write" and "modify" permissions.

I can make it work by combining the SFTP root directory permissions with the umask option in the SFTP server configuration.

Permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x  root  root       /sftproot
drwxrwxr-x  root  sftpgroup  /sftproot/upload_directory
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftponly
  ChrootDirectory /sftproot
  ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /upload_directory -u 0222
```

**Note the `-u 0222` switch.** This applies a [umask](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) to newly-created files, which removes specific permissions.

---

**Results:**

When a user in the sftponly group uploads a new file, it is allowed because of the group-write directory permission. Then the umask option clears the 'w' bits, making the file non-modifiable. The file ends up looking like this:

```
-r--r--r--  {user}  sftponly  /sftproot/upload_directory/filename
```

Great! This is just what I want.

---

**Problem:**

The user can also create directories, which is also what I want. But, the newly-created directories also have their 'w' bits cleared, which prevents any new files from being written within.

---

**Question:**

How can I have the SFTP-created directories remain writable but keep the files read-only?

Any clever ideas?

Comment: Did you happen to find any solutions for this?

Comment: @StephanMøller No, not yet, I ran out of ideas. I keep hoping someone will come by with an answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Based on `sftp-server (5)` manpage, you can use the `-u umask` command line option to override user's umask:

```
     -u umask
             Sets an explicit umask(2) to be applied to newly-created files and directories, instead of
             the user's default mask.
```

So, just set the umask this way so that users don't have write permission anymore.

To set this, refer to `sshd_config(5)` manpage as mentionned in the `sftp-server` manpage:

```
     Command-line flags to sftp-server should be specified in the Subsystem declaration.  See
     sshd_config(5) for more information.
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think you misunderstand. I guess I wasn't clear! I am already using the sftp-server umask option. This is what makes it work as far as it does. But it also effects directories, which is what I want to change.